# JSON.parse returning "scanEscape a"

Tags: javascript, json, qt, syntax-error, qml

I have QML LocalStorage using javaScript. In it I put object via JSON.stringify(). When I try to read the object from DB using JSON.parse() is returning : `scanEscape a` and I did't found a reference to this scan error JSON file:

```
{
  "header": {
    "version": "2.5",
    "createdIn": "PickWorks - Linux",
    "modifiedIn": "PickWorks.appName",
    "modified": "2013/12/07"
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": "We found a love",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Rihana"
      }
    ],
    "transposition": -2,
    "tempo": {
      "type": "bpm",
      "value": "130"
    },
    "key": "C",
    "version": "2.5.4",
    "publisher": "GuitarTab",
    "keywords": [
      "find",
      "love",
      "deny"
    ],
    "verseOrder": "v1 b c v2 b c",
    "themes": [
      "love",
      "hopeless"
    ]
  },
  "lyrics": [
    {
      "title": "v1",
      "text": "[a]Yellow diamonds [F]in the light\n[C]And we're standing [G]side by side\n[a]As your shadow [F]crosses mine\n[C]What it takes to [G]come [a]alive.[F]\n",
      "items": {}
    },
    {
      "title": "v2",
      "text": "[a]Shine a light through [F]an open door\n[C]Love and life [G]I will divide\n[a]Turn away cause [F]I need you more\n[C]Feel the heart-[G]beat in my [a]mind.[F]\n"
    },
    {
      "title": "c",
      "text": "[a]We found love in a [F]hopeless place\n[C]We found love in a [G]hopeless place\n[a]We found love in a [F]hopeless place\n[C]We found love in a [G]hopeless place\n"
    },
    {
      "title": "b",
      "text": "[C]It's the way I'm feeling [G]I just can't [a]deny.[F]\n[C]But I've gotta [G]let it go\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

Q1: What is this error ?
Q2: How to solve it?

P.S.: (Tested on Qt 5.2b & 5.1.1)

Comment: Thanks, Matt for editing... I'm still new to the SO.

Comment: That JSON validates via http://jsonlint.com/, so your problem likely lies elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Moreover, you can see it properly parsed, and again stringified, here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/5T7qc/

Comment: I know that it is valid & parse in browser implementation. The question was about QML (Qt) javaScript. That is where I have problem.

Comment: Right -- only that it's probably something native to Qt's implementation of javascript that's causing the problem, so your problem is a lot more difficult than had the JSON been invalid ;)

Comment: Try to create a more minimal example, then it'd make a good bug report against Qt.

Comment: Created and reported the bugtrack. Also it seems that mostly it is meant as an warning. Because it parses the object just print this error.

Comment: Problem will be soved in QT 5.2.0 (Main release) ... Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was actually some missed debugging log in Qt. Upon creating Bugtrack issue problem was adressed and will be solved in next stable release (Qt 5.2.0).